# Why AOP and DI aren't used together very often

Tags: dependency-injection, aop

I am confused about this line

> Aspect-Oriented Programming and Dependency Injection are very different concepts, but there are limited cases where they fit well together.

from this website

http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-vs-Dependency-Injection

I understand the advantages of DI over AOP, but why <del>aren't they used together more often?</del> why are there only limited cases where they fit together?  Is it because of the way AOP is compiled, that makes using both difficult?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you define "limited cases"? I myself **always** use AOP and DI together.

There are basically three ways to apply AOP, which are:

1. Using code weaving tools such as PostSharp.
2. Using dynamic interception tools such as Castle Dynamic Proxy.
3. Using decorators.

The use of DI with code weaving tools doesn't mix and match very well, and I think that's the reason that the Postsharp site states that "there are limited cases where they fit well together". One reason it doesn't mix and match is because Dependency Injection is about loose coupling, while code weaving hard couples your code and the aspects together at compile time. From a perspective of DI, code weaving becomes an anti-pattern. In section 11.2 of [our book](https://manning.com/seemann2), [Mark](https://blog.ploeh.dk/) and I make this argument very clear. In summary we state:

> *The aim of DI is to manage **Volatile Dependencies** by introducing **Seams** into your application. Theis enables you to centralize the composition of your object graphs inside the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/).*
>
> *This is the complete opposite of hat you achieve when applying compile-time weaving: is causes **Volatile Dependencies** to be coupled to your code at compile-time. This makes it impossible to use proper DI techniques and to safely compose complete object graphs in the application's **Composition Root**. It's for this reason that we say that compile-time weaving is the opposite of DI–using compile-time weaving on **Volatile Dependencies** is an anti-pattern.* [page 355]

If you use dynamic interception, however, which means applying cross-cutting concerns at runtime by generating decorators on the fly it works great with DI and it is integrated easily with most DI libraries out there, and can be done as well when using [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/), which is something we demonstrate in section 11.1.

My personal preference is to use decorators. [My systems](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2011/meanwhile-on-the-command-side-of-my-architecture/) are [designed around](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2011/meanwhile-on-the-query-side-of-my-architecture/) a [few well defined](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2012/writing-highly-maintainable-wcf-services/) generic abstractions, and this allows me to apply cross-cutting concerns at almost all places that are important to my system. That leaves me in very rare cases with a few spots where decorators don't work very well, but this is almost always caused by design flaws. Either by my own limitations as a developer or by design flaws in the .NET framework or some other tool. One famous design flaw is the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. You might have guessed it, but in our book we describe this method in a lot of detail. We spend a complete chapter (10) on this topic.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the famous design flaw in `INotifyPropertyChanged` ?

Comment: @Maarten: Well 'famous' is perhaps a bit an overstatement, but the design around the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface forces you to either write lots of code manually, or do a lot of code generation and  this is to me a clear indication that there is something wrong with the way `INotifyPropertyChanged` works. The solution for me has always been to simply *not* use it.